# Using TRest componet of Tuple

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I'm trying to use the TRest part of the Tuple so that I can say add 14 strings into a tuple list.

```
List<Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, string, string, Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, string, string>>> list = new List<Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, string, string, Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, string, string>>>();
```

Create a second tuple list (list2) which I'm adding 7 strings to:

```
Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, string, string> list2 = Tuple.Create(test8, test9, test10, test11, test12, test13, test14);
```

Then adding all the strings to the first list:

```
list.Add(Tuple.Create(test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7, list2));
```

I'm getting an overload error, I've not tried using this before am I doing something fundamentally incorrect?

Comment: You are aware that you just abused Tuple, right?

Comment: Other than mis-using Tuples? With that many elements in a Tuple with such a complex structure...it just screams "I'm a class!"

Comment: The smell is strong with this code.

Comment: Ha ok, I hadn't realised. I just wanted to add more that 8 components to a tuple list

Comment: It describes how to access here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386918.aspx

Comment: Paul: the overload error is usually accompanied by a "cannot convert" error.  What types are mentioned in that error?

Comment: cannot convert from 'System.Tuple<string,string,string,string,string,string,string,System.Tuple<System.Tuple<string,string,string,string,string,string,string>>>' to 'System.Tuple<string,string,string,string,string,string,string,System.Tuple<string,string,string,string,string,string,string>>

Comment: The problem is that Create() takes a `T8` but automatically wraps it in a `Tuple`, thus it doesn't seem you can use `Tuple.Create()` for the purpose you're looking for.  That is, Create() with 8 args is desgined to do an Octuple of `Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Tuple<T8>>`, it is *not* designed to do anything beyond octuples.

Comment: List<Tuple<No, No, No, No, No, No, No>

Comment: @GazTheDestoyer: I agree it's not elegant...

Comment: Also, it does say in the MSDN: "The static (Shared in Visual Basic) methods of the Tuple class cannot be used to create a tuple with nine or more components."

Comment: I am upvoting this question because sometimes I just like to see the world burn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use TRest on a Tuple, you have to include another Tuple, for example a 16-Tuple of int would be:

```
Tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, 
    Tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, 
        Tuple<int,int>>> t16;
```

Then, accessing elements 1-7:

```
var x1 = t16.Item1;
...
var x7 = t16.Item7;
```

Then, accessing elements 8-14:

```
var x8 = t16.Rest.Item1;
...
var x14 = t16.Rest.Item7;
```

Then, accessing elements 15, 16:

```
var x15 = t16.Rest.Rest.Item1;
var x16 = t16.Rest.Rest.Item2;
```

And so on.  I have a blog post that dives into them a bit [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/03/10/c.net-little-wonders-tuples-and-tuple-factory-methods.aspx) if it's of interest...

**Update:**

Your specific error is because `Tuple.Create()` with 8 type parameters is designed to create Octuples, not Nine-Tuples and beyond.  Thus:

```
Tuple.Create<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>(...)
```

Actually creates a

```
Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Tuple<T8>>
```

Since you are passing a

```
Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, string, string>
```

As the T8, it is wrapping that Septuple inside of the 8th element, which is not what you are expecting.

This is why it is complaining the types don't match, if you notice in the error it has `Tuple<Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, string, string>>` as the T8, which is a septuple wrapped in a tuple.

So you'll either need to write some extensions to Tuple for nine-tuple and above if you want implicit typing, or hand build it:

```
list.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, string, string, 
    Tuple<string, string, string, string, string, string, string>>(
        test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7, list2));
```

Just one of many reasons why large tuples can be confusing.

Comment: Om cheers, I believed I did include another Tuple inside the first Tuple? when declaring the first list. I'll take a look at your blog though and let you know how I get on

Comment: Your error looks like it's having problems with what's coming out of Create(), checking...

Comment: The problem is that Create() takes a T8 but automatically wraps it in a Tuple, thus it doesn't seem you can use Tuple.Create() for the purpose you're looking for. That is, Create() with 8 args is desgined to do an Octuple of Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, Tuple<T8>>, it is not designed to do anything beyond octuples.

Comment: @Paul: just added the explicit syntax (using your `list2`, which you could obviously use Tuple.Create for list2, just not for list1)

Comment: Yeah that works perfectly, I don't think after all the comments that Tuple is the way to go with this. I was just intrigued to see how to do this. So thanks for all the help

Comment: @Paul: No problem.  `Tuple<>` is good for small sets and has other purposes, but most of the time you're better off with an explicit class with meaningful property names.